# how to make automatic copyright webpage footer in php using a function

Tags: php, copyright-display

I want a code or function that will show copyright from starting year to current year.

## **Example**

```
© 2012-2013
© 1998-2013
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## **Current year only**

```
&copy; <?php echo date("Y") ?>
```

## **With start year**

```
&copy; 2008-<?php echo date("Y") ?>
```

## **Start date with error protection**

```
<?php function auto_copyright($year = 'auto'){ ?>
   <?php if(intval($year) == 'auto'){ $year = date('Y'); } ?>
   <?php if(intval($year) == date('Y')){ echo intval($year); } ?>
   <?php if(intval($year) < date('Y')){ echo intval($year) . ' - ' . date('Y'); } ?>
   <?php if(intval($year) > date('Y')){ echo date('Y'); } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

## **Usage:**

```
<?php auto_copyright(); // 2011?>

<?php auto_copyright('2010');  // 2010 - 2011 ?>
```

Comment: Formatted answer in a minute? :O

Comment: i came across the same problem i found the answer and copied from my backup and pasted here. ;)

Comment: @TusharGupta Hehe that was quick ;)